# dropdown list moving towards scrolling

Tags: css, jsp, jsf

[image: User clicks dropdown]

From above screen shot user clicks an dropdown values are shown

[image: While user scrolling dropdown then values also moves as per mouse movement]

I m facing an problem in dropdown and calendar while user select an dropdown and scroll mouse up and down then dropdown values also move as per scrolling ..

Comment: So what's the question here?! What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: what is your questions and show the codes.Just showing the image how can we help you

Comment: My problem is jsf dropdown,calendar values moves up and down when i scroll my mouse

Comment: Are you really using JSP? The UI is recognizable as PrimeFaces (at least, jQuery UI based). PrimeFaces doesn't support JSP. In any case, please tell about the component library being used.